# How do I add a Array to my php variables, loops wont work with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm trying to put my variables into an array or arrays, and loop them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    html {
        background-color: bisque;
    }

    h1 {

        display: block;
        text-align: center;

    }

    h2 {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        color: saddlebrown;
    }

    img {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 800px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {

        text-align: center;
        color: saddlebrown;
    }

</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dynamic web pages with PHP</title>

</head>


<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="main-navigation">

        </nav>
    </header>

    <?php 

     $Cartitle = "My favourite Cars";
                    $Carname = "HRV";
                    $Carprice = "CAD-$23300";
                    $Carimg = "http://direct.automobiles.honda.com/images/2016/hr-v/exterior-gallery-new/2016-honda-hrv-front-view.jpg";
                    $Cardescription = "HRV is a mini suv made by Honda";

                   $Carname2 = "CHR";
                   $Carprice2 = "CAD-$23675";
                    $Carimg2 = "https://d1bxbrgbmu84na.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/16093812/CHR.jpg";
                  $Cardescription2 = "HRV is a mini suv made by Toyota";

                  $Carname3 = "RDX";
                   $Carprice3 = "CAD-$43990";
                    $Carimg3 = "https://www.acura.ca/Content/acura.ca/e270f141-7f67-4fe2-99bd-e808e3c3c2d7/MediumSizedFeature/03_rdx19_overview_MediumFeature_mobile.jpg";
                  $Cardescription3 = "RDX is a large SUV made by Acura";

 ?>


    <?php

    echo "<h1>$Cartitle<h2>$Carname <p>$Carprice <p> $Cardescription <br>  <img src=$Carimg></p></h2><h1><br>"; 
    echo "<h2>$Carname2 <p>$Carprice2 <p> $Cardescription2 <br>  <img src=$Carimg2></p></h2><br>";
    echo "<h2>$Carname3 <p>$Carprice3 <p> $Cardescription3 <br>  <img src=$Carimg3></p></h2>";

        ?>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Then put them into arrays. You'll want a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: This seems like a fundamental issue that can probably be answered by the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php & https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php You can either create a 2D array, where the first level is an index (grouping) each having another array of your variables or you can create a class to represent a car and create an array of those objects.

Comment: Your statement in your question is incorrect. Loops such as `foreach` work just fine with arrays and are what you're looking for in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example (style and add to it as needed)

```
$cars[] = ['name'  => 'HRV',
           'price' => 'CAD-$23300',
           'img'   => 'http://direct.automobiles.honda.com/images/2016/hr-v/exterior-gallery-new/2016-honda-hrv-front-view.jpg',
           'desc'  => 'HRV is a mini suv made by Honda',
           ];
$cars[] = ['name'  => 'CHR' ,
           'price' => 'CAD-$23675' ,
           'img'   => 'https://d1bxbrgbmu84na.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/16093812/CHR.jpg' ,
           'desc'  => 'RDX is a large SUV made by Acura' ,
           ];

echo '<h1>My favourite Cars</h1>';

foreach ($cars as $detail) {

echo '<h2>' . $detail['name']  . '<p>' . 
              $detail['price'] . '<p>' . 
              $detail['desc']  . '<br>' . 
'<img src=' . $detail['img']   . '</p></h2>';

}
```

Comment: never i got it '<img src=' . $detail['img']   . '</img>';

Comment: i can only get the bottom image to display? how do i get both to display?

Comment: Your original question only had 1 image for each car. I see nothing about a second image.